# angular implement mat checkbox inside ejs grid

Tags: angular

In my angular project I am using ejs grid in parent component . This ejs grid should have checkbox selection for each of the row and I need to get all the rows that are checked and need to pass these selected rows to child component (app-side-nav>) using @input  , and everytime a row is checked/unchecked it should reflect in child component .

my .html file

```
 <app-side-nav 
    [notifyItemProcessed]="processOrderItems" [selectedRows]="selection.selected"></app-side-nav>

  <ejs-grid #grid id="dataview" [dataSource]="data" [allowPaging]='true' [pageSettings]='initialPage'>

            <e-columns>
              
            <e-column width='50'>
                <ng-template #template let-data> 
                <div> 
                    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                </div>
              </ng-template>
            </e-column>
           <e-column
                *ngFor="let column of columnsList"
                [field]="column.key"
                [headerText]="column.header"
                [width]="column.width"
                [textAlign]="column.textAlign"
                [headerTextAlign]="column.hederAlign"
                [visible]="column.visible"
                [type]="column.type"
                [format]="column.format"
              >
              </e-column>
            </e-columns>
          </ejs-grid>
```

my .ts file

```
export interface PeriodicElement {

  assetName: string;
  dborModel: string;
  environment: string;
  primaryIpAddress: string;
  
}

export class GridViewTableComponent implements OnInit {

selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);

getRemoteData(url) {
    this.http.get(url).
    subscribe((resp:any) => {
       this.data = resp.content;
       }
    );
  }

/** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    var res: any = []; 
    console.log("selection is"+ this.selection.selected);
    console.log('data inside isall selected'+ this.data);
    res = this.data;
    const numRows = res.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    var res:any = []; 
    console.log('data inside mastertoggle'+ this.data);
    res = this.data;
    
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() : res.forEach( row => this.selection.select(row));
    
  }

}
```

in child component.ts file

```
export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  set selectedRows(val: any) {  
       this._item = val;
       this.checkedRows = val;
  }
}
```

This mat checkbox works fine with mat table but not working with ejs grid .